# How can loop over an array of objects and return true/false when at least one of the object's properties matches the properties of a test object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

i have an array that looks like this

```js
let arrayExample = 
[
 {
 "size":"6M",
 "color":"Blue"
 }
,
 {
 "size":"2M",
 "color":"Yellow"
 }
]
```

currently, to return all elements of a specific color or a specific size I use this approach

```js
var allColors= arrayExample.map(i=>i.color)

return [{"color":"Blue"}].some((val)=>  allColors.includes(val.color))
```

my question is how to return a truthy value whenever i found an element with the exact combination i desire

as quoted in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

> Return value
> true if the callback function returns a truthy value for at least one element in the array. Otherwise, false.

my current approach to this is

```js
var allColors= arrayExample.map(i=>i.color)
var allSizes= arrayExample.map(i=>i.size)

return [{"color":"Blue","size":"2M"}].some((val)=>  allColors.includes(val.color) && allSizes.includes(val.size)
```

this approach doesn't work for my purposes, knowing that even if there is no item in my `arrayExample` with the combination `[{"color":"Blue","size":"2M"}]`, it would still return `true` because of the 2M size of the 2nd item of my array

here is a Jsfiddle to test my situation https://jsfiddle.net/8htjpyb9/1/

I would like to thank you if you got this far and also thank you for any and all help, I hope you are having a good day

*edit -> i would like to emphasize that .filter does not work for my problem because of the rest of the code this situation is embedded in.

I am only interested in returning a value of true whenever it finds the exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), iterate over the array
- In every iteration, using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), check if any of the `combinations` match the current object.
- To do so, you can use [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check a combination of properties matching the current object.

```js
const array = [ { id: 1, size: '6M', color: 'Blue' }, { ld: 2, size: '2M', color: 'Yellow' }, { id: 3, size: '6M', color: 'Blue' } ];

const combinations = [ { "color": "Blue", "size": "6M" } ];

const matches = array.map(current => 
  combinations.some(combination => 
    Object.entries(combination).every(([key, value]) => 
      current[key] === value
    )
  )
);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: .filter does not work for my problem because of the rest of the code this situation is embedded in.

I am only interested in returning a value of true whenever it finds the exact match.

Comment: @GabrielFaria, so for the above example, it should return a list of booleans ``[true, false, true]``?

Comment: my code is in a for loop situation so for the above example it should return true for the first iteration aka { id: 1 ...}, return false for { id: 2 ... } and true again for { id: 3 .... }

im looking for a return just like .some

as quoted in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

"Return value
true if the callback function returns a truthy value for at least one element in the array. Otherwise, false."

Comment: Please confirm if this is what you're trying to do: you have an array of objects. You also have another array of combinations which basically objects with different attributes and values. For every object, we need to return true if it matches any of the combinations, false otherwise.

Comment: Ok, I believe my answer solves the issue, what's missing?

Comment: I had to make some minor changes due to the situation my code was in but this is for sure the correct answer

I have no words to describe my gratitude, thank you friend have a great day and a great 2022

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for this?

```js
const getItem = (arr, toFind) => {
  const {size, color} = toFind;
  return arr.filter(item => item.color === color && item.size === size).length > 0
};
let arrayExample = [{
    "size": "6M",
    "color": "Blue",
    "material": "plastic"
  },
  {
    "size": "2M",
    "color": "Yellow",
    "material": "leather"
  }
]


const res = getItem(arrayExample,{"size": "6M","color": "Blue"})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: This solution does not work for my problem, I think I did not emphasize enough that I need a solution that returns the value of true whenever it finds the exact combination 

.filter does not work for my problem because of the rest of the code that this situation is inserted

Comment: Just add .length > 0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the objects the match [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would be an easier approach. Pass in a set of data, and a test object to a function and return only those object that have the same size and colour values as the test object.

```js
const data=[{id: 1,size:'6M',color:'Blue'},{ld:2,size:'2M',color:'Yellow'},{id:3,size:'6M',color:'Blue'}];

const test = { size: '6M', color: 'Blue' };

function getExact(data, test) {
  return data.filter(obj => {
    return (
      obj.size === test.size
      && obj.color === test.color
    );
  });
}
console.log(getExact(data, test));
```

If you only want to return `true/false` if the properties of an array object matches the properties of a test object `some` *is* the better option.

```js
const data=[{id: 1,size:'6M',color:'Blue'},{ld:2,size:'2M',color:'Yellow'},{id:3,size:'6M',color:'Blue'}];

const test = { size: '6M', color: 'Blue' };
const test2 = { size: '5M', color: 'Green' };

function getExact(data, test) {
  return data.some(obj => {
    return (
      obj.size === test.size
      && obj.color === test.color
    );
  });
}

console.log(getExact(data, test));
console.log(getExact(data, test2));
```